# debugging in MVP4G project

Tags: debugging, gwt, mvp4g

I have created a maven gwt project(2.7.0) and then integrated MVP4G into it.
All is working fine but now when I wanted to debug my code to understand the flow, I am not able to debug the code.

```
Maven goal : gwt:debug
```

I am running the above mentioned goal and then I am running remote application which is providing me and url and when i launch that url I am not able to debug the code.

Please can anyone guide me on how we should debug this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to debug the generated code?

Comment: @ElHoss : actually I want to debug the java code in the eclipse to check the  flow and see where it goes wrong to check exceptions. Earlier with gwt-2.4.0 plugin i was able to do it but now having trouble with it :(

Comment: I a using mp4g with GWT 2.7 and the current plugin. To Debug, just add the sdbg plugin (take a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icJEa5lcJaQ) or debug inside the browser. I think Chrome is the best choice.

Comment: @ElHoss : Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. Even if it is not up to the mark as earlier but it fix the soul purpose. It also crashes sometime but hoping will be fixed in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Debug, just add the sdbg plugin (take a look [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icJEa5lcJaQ)) or debug inside the browser if you are familiar with browser debugging. I think Chrome is the best choice. Credits:El Hoss